# According to Wesleyan-Arminianism, does God fail?

Tags: nature-of-god, soteriology, hell, arminianism

According to Wesleyan-Arminianism, does God try His absolute hardest to save all of mankind- but ultimately fails and has no other choice but to send a majority of mankind to have their flesh burned in eternal hellfire?

This question is similar to *[How does the Arminian view of salvation account for God's sovereignty?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/how-does-the-arminian-view-of-salvation-account-for-gods-sovereignty)*, but I'm not looking for a reconciliation of free-will and God's sovereignty. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best illustrations I have seen in support of the Arminian concept is a "Dennis the Menace" cartoon in which Dennis has a boy on the ground and is sitting on him with his fist poised to punch him in the face.  The caption is, "Alright Dennis, I'll be you're best friend."  Anybody who knows anything about love knows it cannot be taken, it can only be given.  God whose nature is love knows this most of all.  He created man with free will and the ability to love whom we choose.  If we look at His creation, including ourselves, we see the evidence of this everywhere.

That is from me.  Officially, Wesleyan Arminians believe that for God to overcome man's choice to resist His grace would be an infringement on man's libertarian free will and that free will is tantamount to God truly being loved.  To consider this a failure on God's part would indicate a lack of understanding of God and His nature.  The only limitations on God are the ones He places on Himself.

Comment: I believe this is a correct answer (as far as it goes) and have upvoted as such. However it would be greatly improved if you could cite a Wesleyan Arminian source in support of it (showing your working as it were).

Comment: Thank you Michael, but I was wondering if God **tries His absolute hardest** to save all of mankind. That is my main question. I only ask about hell because it seems like He is going to fail at what He's trying His hardest at, so despite His loving nature, He will have no other choice than to send them to the hell He created to have their flesh burned forever. Is this correct?

Comment: I've come up with more than my share of "What if's..."  I've learned to concentrate on "what is".  The fact is God does not 'try', He 'does'.  He could have created robots that obey His every command, but that is obedience, not love.  If you are a parent, you will understand that the hardest thing you can do is let your child fail.  But, if you never let him/her fail, they will never learn and never really live their own life.  When you see the phrase, "God is love", it's not just a sound bite.

Comment: Thank you@Michael. I am a parent, and one thing I've learned is that my children love me "because" I love them. I agree that God is love, and afterwards, the Apostle John says "**There is no fear in love**; but perfect love casteth out fear: because fear hath torment. He that feareth is not made perfect in love. We love him, **because he first loved us**." 1 John 4:18 God could have made robots, or he could have made a place so terrible that anyone who loves him must first become terrified of the excruciating pain he is going to subject them to if they don't. Or He could cause us to love Him.